# ¿Qué es exactamente el selector /deep/ en CSS?

Tags: css, html5

He estado investigando acerca del selector `/deep/`, debido a que he tenido que modificar los estilos de un input de la librería material design de google forzadamente con ese selector.

He encontrado que es utilizado para encapsular los estilos de un componente para que no salgan fuera de la página, pero no encuentro un claro ejemplo para terminar de entenderlo correctamente.

1. ¿Qué es `/deep/`?
2. ¿Para qué es utilizado?
3. ¿Problemas? Ej: compatibilidad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Los componenetes web de HTML5 ofrecen encapsulación completa de estilos CSS.

Esto significa que:

- Los estilos definidos dentro de un componente no pueden salirse y afectar al resto de la página
- Los estilos definidos en el nivel de página no modifican los estilos propios del componente

Sin embargo, a veces se desea tener reglas de nivel de página para manipular la presentación de los elementos componentes definidos dentro de su sombra DOM. Para hacer esto, se agrega `/deep/` al selector CSS.

`/deep/` es por tanto un combinador.

Ver: [What do /deep/ and ::shadow mean in a CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25609678/5587982)

---

Quizá [la doc de w3.org, en el apartado 3.2.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#deep-combinator) ayude a entenderlo:

#### 3.2.4 Selección de sombras: el combinador / deep /

Cuando se encuentre un combinador `/deep/` en un selector, reemplace todos los elementos de la lista de coincidencias de selectores con cada elemento accesible desde el elemento original atravesando cualquier número de listas secundarias o árboles de sombra.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos un componente con un árbol de sombra como el siguiente:

```
<x-foo>
    <"shadow tree">
      <div>
        <span id="not-top">...</span>
      </div>
      <span id="top">...</span>
      <x-bar>
        <"shadow tree">
          <span id="nested">...</span>
        </>
      </x-bar>
    </>
  </x-foo>
```

Para una hoja de estilo en el documento externo, el selector `x-foo/deep/span` selecciona los tres elementos : `#top`, # `not-top` y `#nested`.

**Problema:**

Esto es básicamente un combinador súper-descendente. Si el combinador de descendientes tenía un glifo real, sería potencialmente interesante simplemente duplicarlo. ¿Tal vez podamos darle al combinador de descendientes un pseudónimo de `>>`, ya que es un combinador super-hijo? Entonces `/deep/` podría ser escrito `>>>`

#### Compatibilidad

El combinador `deep` ha sido declarado *deprecated* en algunas librerías como [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade) o Angular ([ver página oficial](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) y también [esta pregunta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42134355/5587982)), lo mismo que en [Chrome](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-reviews/ufQPZ2ovsac).

Es un tema que requiere más profundización, ya que dependerá de las librerías que estés utilizando.

Estos enlaces podrían ayudar a formarse un criterio sobre la compatibilidad:

- [Shadow DOM 201](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/)
- [CSS Variables: Why Should You Care?](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/css-variables-why-should-you-care?hl=en)
- [Chrome 49 Beta: CSS custom properties, background sync with service workers, and new ES2015 features](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/chrome-49-beta-css-custom-properties.html)

Answer (score 4):

Primero hay que saber lo que es *shadow DOM*: que básicamente es un DOM dentro de otro DOM, parecido a un `iframe` pero formando parte del mismo documento. El *shadow DOM*  tiene sus propios estilos que no afectan al DOM principal y los estilos de éste no afectan al *shadow DOM*.

Para poder aplicar estilos desde el DOM principal al *shadow DOM* se usa el selector `/deep/` que atraviesa ese encapsulamiento. En los últimos borradores ya no aparece `/deep/` sino `>>>`: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping-1/#deep-combinator.

El soporte de los navegadores de *shadow DOM* todavía es bastante limitado, solo Chrome y Opera lo soportan, Safari parcialmente.

---

Una forma de ver como funciona shadow DOM es usando las herramientas de desarrollador de Chrome, en las opciones se activa la opción `Show user agent shadow DOM` y si inspeccionas elementos como `<video<`, `<audio>` y algún otro puedes ver como el navegador construye un DOM encapsulado dentro del elemento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]